# axis values for custom points in listplot

Tags: plotting

Let's say I have a listplot like so:

```
ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]]]
```

I want my plot to mark the x,y values for the values associated with say, the 5th, and 10th points in the input. I would be interested in any of the following:

- marking simply the y values so have 11 and 29 in the y axis
- marking both x and y axis: ie show {5,11} and {10,29} in the x and y axis respectively.

with, or without perpendicular lines connecting the points to axes.

The point of this, is to give the reader of the plot, a sense of scale for given points of interest.

Do I have to superimpose different plots on each other or can I do it by some config on the listplot itself?

Comment: Use `Ticks` ? For example: `ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Ticks -> {{5, 10}, Prime[{5, 10}]}, 
 Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed,
   Line[{{5, 0}, {5, Prime[5]}}],
   Line[{{10, 0}, {10, Prime[10]}}],
   Line[{{0, Prime[5]}, {5, Prime[5]}}],
   Line[{{0, Prime[10]}, {10, Prime[10]}}]
   }]`

Comment: ah! how did I miss that! yeah that would do the trick :)

Comment: This is a bit more general: `With[{points = {5, 10, 13}}, 
 ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Ticks -> {points, Prime[points]}, 
  Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed,
    {Line[{{#, 0}, {#, Prime[#]}}], 
       Line[{{0, Prime[#]}, {#, Prime[#]}}]} & /@ points
    }]]`

Comment: @flinty little improvement on this ^ https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226205/8988

Answer (score 1):

This is a more readable and reusable version of the suggestion by [@fliny](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226020/axis-values-for-custom-points-in-listplot?noredirect=1#comment575112_226020)

```
With[
  {
    points = Table[{n,Fibonacci[n]}, {n, 7}],
    sampleValues = {1,5,7}
  },
  ListPlot[
    points,
    Joined -> True,
    Ticks -> {sampleValues , points[[All,2]][[sampleValues]]},
    Epilog -> {
      Dashed,
      {
        Line[{Projection[points[[#]], {1,0}], points[[#]]}], (*X-axis projection*)
        Line[{Projection[points[[#]], {0,1}], points[[#]]}]  (*Y-axis projection*)
      } & /@ sampleValues
    }
  ]
]
```

it will produce the following:

[image]